# Verify digital signature with public key in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, openssl, public-key-encryption

**How to Verify digital signature with public key in iOS without using any third party code(e.g.) open SSL?**

I need to verify Digital signature in iOS App with a public key. Can some one help me how to achieve that without using third party software.

I am trying below code but the problem is I don't have certificate in my App so can not create *SecTrustRef*.

CODE:

```
    NSString *certPath              = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yyy" 
                                                             ofType:@"xxx"];
    SecCertificateRef myCertificate = nil;
    NSData *certificateData         = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile :certPath];
    myCertificate                   = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)certificateData);

    SecPolicyRef myPolicy           = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef trustRef;
    SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(myCertificate, myPolicy, &trustRef);
    SecKeyRef keyRef      = SecTrustCopyPublicKey (trustRef);


    BOOL status = SecKeyRawVerify (keyRef,
                              kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1,
                              (const uint8_t *)[data bytes],
                              (size_t)[data length],
                              (const uint8_t *)[signature bytes],
                              (size_t)[signature length]
                              );
```

I have the following:

- Public Key (NSString*)
- Signature (NSString*)
- Data (NSString*)

Please help me what all option I have in iOS SDK if I don't want to use ant third party open source.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please accept so question will be marked as solved and help other users. thanks

Comment: Did you ever got some solution or you created .pem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can package your public key in a X509 certificate to use the iOS built in functions easily, using openSSL:

```
openssl req -x509 -out public_key.pem -outform pem -new -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private_key.pem
```

the PEM format is base64 encoded, you can switch the -outform to DER to get binary file.
you can import the PEM format by adding a const NSString to your program and adding category to NSData with this function:

```
- (id) initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string {
    NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

    if( string ) {
        unsigned long ixtext = 0;
        unsigned long lentext = 0;
        unsigned char ch = 0;
        unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[3]; // buffer sizes fixed by AOL LLC
        short i = 0, ixinbuf = 0;
        BOOL flignore = NO;
        BOOL flendtext = NO;
        NSData *base64Data = nil;
        const unsigned char *base64Bytes = nil;

        // Convert the string to ASCII data.
        base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
        mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[base64Data length]];
        lentext = [base64Data length];

        while( YES ) {
            if( ixtext >= lentext ) break;
            ch = base64Bytes[ixtext++];
            flignore = NO;

            if( ( ch >= 'A' ) && ( ch <= 'Z' ) ) ch = ch - 'A';
            else if( ( ch >= 'a' ) && ( ch <= 'z' ) ) ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
            else if( ( ch >= '0' ) && ( ch <= '9' ) ) ch = ch - '0' + 52;
            else if( ch == '+' ) ch = 62;
            else if( ch == '=' ) flendtext = YES;
            else if( ch == '/' ) ch = 63;
            else flignore = YES;

            if( ! flignore ) {
                short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
                BOOL flbreak = NO;

                if( flendtext ) {
                    if( ! ixinbuf ) break;
                    if( ( ixinbuf == 1 ) || ( ixinbuf == 2 ) ) ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                    else ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                    ixinbuf = 3;
                    flbreak = YES;
                }

                inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

                if( ixinbuf == 4 ) {
                    ixinbuf = 0;
                    outbuf [0] = ( inbuf[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4 );
                    outbuf [1] = ( ( inbuf[1] & 0x0F ) << 4 ) | ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x3C ) >> 2 );
                    outbuf [2] = ( ( inbuf[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( inbuf[3] & 0x3F );

                    for( i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++ )
                        [mutableData appendBytes:&outbuf[i] length:1];
                }

                if( flbreak )  break;
            }
        }
    }

    self = [self initWithData:mutableData];
    return self;
}
```

ofcourse you pull this file into the certificateData 
if you want to use your existing public key just pull it out and write it in a X509 cert format using openSSL

```
$ openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out pub.der -outform DER -pubout
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If your key data is packaged as PKCS12 data, use SecPKCS12Import to import it and use the public key.

Comment: Its .pem format; its just a NSString which I got from server response header

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637328/import-pem-encoded-x-509-certificate-into-ios-keychain

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a digest (hash) of your data to the verification function. See [iOS: Verifying a File With a Certificate and Signature - Public Key is Wrong, Verification Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438257/ios-verifying-a-file-with-a-certificate-and-signature-public-key-is-wrong-ve)

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface HDSecurityPolicy :AFSecurityPolicy
@end

@implementation HDSecurityPolicy
///pem formate(base64) ->  NSData
- (void)setPinnedCertificates:(NSSet *)pinnedCertificates {
    [super setPinnedCertificates:pinnedCertificates];
    if (self.pinnedCertificates) {
        NSMutableSet *mutablePinnedPublicKeys = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[self.pinnedCertificates count]];
        for (NSData *pubCertificate in self.pinnedCertificates) {
            id publicKey = [HDSecurityPolicy publicSecKeyFromKeyBits:pubCertificate];
            if (!publicKey) {
                continue;
            }
            [mutablePinnedPublicKeys addObject:publicKey];
        }
        [self setValue:mutablePinnedPublicKeys forKey:@"pinnedPublicKeys"];
    }
}

// 从公钥证书文件中获取到公钥的SecKeyRef指针
+ (id)publicSecKeyFromKeyBits:(NSData *)givenData {
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    options[(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType] = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA;
    options[(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyClass] = (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic;

    NSError *error = nil;
    CFErrorRef ee = (__bridge CFErrorRef)error;
    ////'SecKeyCreateWithData' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer
    id ret = (__bridge_transfer id)SecKeyCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)givenData, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options, &ee);
    if (error) {
        return nil;
    }
    return ret;
}
@end
```